# Using morphia’s fromDBObject without DataStore

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am working on an application that directly uses Java MongoDB driver for Mongo queries.

I’d like to use Morphia to map retrieved Documents to my POJOs and vice versa (but I do not want to do queries through Morphia itself).

I am trying to achieve this with Morphia 1.1, however the `fromDBObject` in this version requires Morphia’s `DataStore` as an argument (previous versions did without it) – and I do not want to give Morphia actual connection to the database. I am not using references to join data from different collections – so when transforming an already retrieved document to POJO it is not needed to retrieve any additional data from the DB.

Can I achieve this in the version 1.1 (eg. by creating and passing an empty, nonfunctional datastore (how to create it?), or just by passing null)?

If not, I can live with the older (1.0.1) version – but does that make sense?

And if not – what would be the best solution for mapping POJOs to Mongo documents – are there any other, currently maintained, libraries to achieve this?

And, again, if not – what would be the best way to implement this functionality myself? The solution should be as generic as possible regarding document and POJO classes schema, I am OK with annotating my entity classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try passing in null for the Datastore?  It's used for resolving any `@Reference`d fields for the most part.  You should be fine just passing null.  But as always, "try it and see."

Comment: I am rewriting my classes now to use Morphia (and get rid of Jongo), and I’ll try that, thanks. I asked the question, because passing null as a first argument in Java just looks strange, and wanted to be sure.

Comment: OK. After some struggle with some unit and integration tests I come to the place where it works – with `null` passed as DataStore to Morphia. Thanks again. :)